# Ansible Galaxy roles install in to a specific directory?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-galaxy

So I figured I should start using Ansible Galaxy when possible, instead of writing my own roles. I just installed my first role and it was installed to `/etc/local/ansible/roles` (I am on OSX).

Now I wonder how you install this roles where I actually need it? Do I just copy the role to where I need it or is there an Ansible way of doing it?

Comment: Just curious: why do you need to copy the role somewhere else? One of the purposes of ansible-galaxy is to install the role only once in your system and then using it from the playbook doesn't matter where your ansible projects live in your system.

Comment: Ansible was new to me and I knew no better.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, you would copy them according to a sample project structure:

```
site.yml
webservers.yml
fooservers.yml
kubernetes.yaml
roles/
   common/
     files/
     templates/
     tasks/
     handlers/
     vars/
     meta/
   webservers/
     files/
     templates/
     tasks/
     handlers/
     vars/
     meta/
   kubernetes/
     files/
     templates/
     tasks/
     handlers/
     vars/
     meta/
```

or you can just run `ansible-galaxy` with the `-p ROLES_PATH` or `--roles-path=ROLES_PATH` option to install it under `/your/project/root`

You can also use the `/etc/local/ansible` directory as your project root if you'd like to.

Additionally, you can get help by running the command `ansible-galaxy install --help`

Comment: Awesome @Rico! I thought there would be such a command, but its tricky to find any proper documentation on Galaxy at this point.

Comment: The `ansible-galaxy` help is slightly obtuse as well, but run `ansible-galaxy [command] --help` to get command-specific help (in this case, `install` command).

Comment: If I run the install with `--roles-path=relative/folder/from/my/project`, does that means the role will be installed in the folder `relative/folder/from/my/project`?

Answer (score 45):

In general, I stick all my shared roles in a single master folder that gets shared across all my projects. This avoids the tediousness of manual copy/pasting and updating multiple copies of the same role.

Than I modify each project's `ansible.cfg` to tell `ansible` to look for roles in that master folder in addition to the local project folder.

Sample `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ~/Code/ansible_roles
```

Ansible first searches the local project for a role, then searches the `roles_path`. You can specify multiple paths by separating them with colons.

By default, `ansible-galaxy install username.rolename` will install the role to the `roles_path` configured in `ansible.cfg`, so that's pretty much all you need to do.

Occasionally I want to install the role into the specific project and not the master folder. For example, to avoid version conflicts when two roles have role dependencies that require different versions of the same role. In that case, you can use the `-p ROLES_PATH` or `--roles-path=ROLES_PATH` option:

```
ansible-galaxy install username.rolename -p ~/Code/project_deploy/ansible/roles/
```

In Ansible 1.9, you can manually specify where you want a role to be installed in your project's `requirements.yml`. Unfortunately, [this `path` param was removed in Ansible 2](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13563):

```
# from galaxy
- src: jeffwidman.elasticsearch

# from private github repo, installing to a relative path
- src: https://github.com/jeffwidman/private_ansible_role
  path: vagrant/roles/
```

If you want to customize things further, there's an open issue to [add support for multiple `ansible.cfg`  files](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11175) which would let you easily set `roles_path` at varying levels of specificity. Ansible will read `ANSIBLE_CONFIG`, `ansible.cfg` in the current working directory, `.ansible.cfg` in the home directory or `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`, whichever it finds first.

Comment: I prefer using tools like virtualenv and nvm which keep every project's dependencies sandboxed.  I just tried `roles_path = .galaxy` in my project's `ansible.cfg` and galaxy happily installed dependencies there!  It even created the folder.  Seems like a great way to manage galaxy dependencies.

Comment: The downside of that approach is that if you are reusing the same role across separate projects, then when you do a bugfix in the role, you'll need to remember to fix all copies. Most bugfixes in the generic roles that I use are due to linux changes, etc so they aren't local to a single project.

Answer (score 34):

Here is how I solved the problem of dealing with galaxy roles and works for any platform.

Edit your `ansible.cfg` file, which should be part of your source control and add this to it:

```
roles_path = roles.galaxy:roles
```

Create a directory named `roles.galaxy` and from now on, when you do `ansible-galaxy install xxx.yyy`, it will install into `roles.galaxy`.

You will continue to keep your local roles inside the `roles` directory and the community ones in `roles.galaxy`. Both of them are supposed to be kept in your git repo.

Don't ever consider installing them on from galaxy, this would be a big security risk in addition to adding several additional points of failure.

Comment: Could you further explain the security risk and additional points of failure? How would it differ from running `pip install -r requirements.txt` if the version is properly pinned?

Comment: I think @KevinLondon is saying that you shouldn't continually install from Galaxy or other package providers, you should 'vendor' the code (commit your code to your repository).

Comment: Yuck, really?  I don't do that for npm or composer.  Or does the lock file reduce the security risk?

Comment: Is `galaxy.roles` and `roles.galaxy` the same (but misspelled), or should they differ?

Comment: @GregBell You should pin dependencies so that you aren't surprised or put into trouble when a new version releases and breaks something, or when multiple people are using different versions.

I'm not sure there's any supported lockfile stuff, so vendoring is proabably what ends up making the most sense. It's pretty easy to upgrade however so I wouldn't personally mind doing that.

Comment: Where is this directory `roles.galaxy` supposed to be created?

Answer (score 17):

I am probably answering this question too late. But what you want can be done with a single command:

```
ansible-galaxy install -p ./roles thefinn93.letsencrypt
```

will install the letsencrypt role to the roles directory and you don't need to copy things around.

Comment: This was the most useful answer for me.  It's especially useful in automation pipelines that pull down roles/collections on demand and you can then place them in a path that's not part of the version control repository.

Answer (score 3):

To have your roles saved within your repository folder (which is what you likely want, having all your stuff version-controlled is one of the infrastructure-as-code), and assuming this is your directory layout:

```
repo-folder
    inventory     << likely you have this already
    roles         << this, too
    roles.galaxy  << create if you dont have it
    site.yml      << or whatever your playbook is called
    ansible.cfg   << repo-local config overriding gloabal ~/.ansible.cfg
```

Open the above shown `ansible.cfg` (or create it anew if you do not already have one), and add this content:

```
[defaults]
roles_path = roles.galaxy:roles
```

Running `ansible-galaxy install SOMETHING` will then save its contents within the `roles.galaxy` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I desired a global path for my roles. You can do this my putting an ansible.cfg at ~/.ansible.cfg. A project based one will always take precedence.

```
cat ~/.ansible.cfg
[defaults]
roles_path = ~/.ansible/roles
```